# Trying to import arrays of color?

Tags: java, arrays

bSo, I have 3 integer arrays and they are,
    colorRed[];
    colorGreen[];
    colorBlue[];
    What I am trying to accomplish is to make it so the block that I am making which is twelve by twelve in squares. Each square has its own color. I have a ton of it done and all of it works but a new feature I am trying to add which is an option to import the array of color that you want for all 3 color arrays. I need to enter the array as an string and I have converted it to an integer. The problem is, I can't get it to work! The squares always end up black instead of the color. Here is the code.

```
    public void importing()
{
    String Red = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the red? ");
    String Green = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the green? ");
    String Blue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the blue? ");
    String[] redred = Red.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "").split(",");
    String[] greengreen = Green.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "").split(",");
    String[] blueblue = Blue.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "").split(",");

    int[] red1 = new int[redred.length];
    int[] green1 = new int [greengreen.length];
    int[] blue1 = new int [blueblue.length]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < redred.length; i++)
    {
        try{
            red1[i] = Integer.parseInt(redred[i]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < greengreen.length; k++)
    {
        try{
            green1[k] = Integer.parseInt(greengreen[k]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
    }
    for(int l = 0; l < blueblue.length; l++)
    {
        try{
            blue1[l] = Integer.parseInt(blueblue[l]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
    }
    for(int m = 0; m < 144; m++)
    {
        colorRed[m] = red1[m];
        colorGreen[m] = green1[m];
        colorBlue[m] = blue1[m];
    }

}
```

Sorry I put the wrong variable on the colored[m] = redred[m] and all of the others.

Also, the top left square actually changes the color to the correct color.

Comment: are you sure you want to enter like `{50, 90, 100}` in `InputDialog`?

Comment: any sample input that you can share? check if `split` worked as you expected. You could also check `colorRed`, `colorGreen`, `colorBlue` to make sure correct integer values are there.

Comment: As @wns349 pointed out, use `System.out.println()` to print your values to console.

Comment: `for(int m = 0; m < 144; m++)` This loop causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if you entered less than 144 numbers in to the dialog box. You are also swallowing exceptions (`catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}`). You need to investigate your problem more thoroughly before you post it here. You are getting an exception or something and we can't tell what it is based on the information you've given us. You also need to tell us what input you are using that causes the problem you observed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the values you store in the red1, green1, and blue1 arrays anywhere.  The strings are parsed to integers and then discarded.

You claim colorRed[] is an integer array, yet you are storing redred[k] into it, which is a String.  If so, the code would not compile.